# replace array value with hashmap values

Tags: java, hashmap

```
        HashMap<String, String> apos = new HashMap<String, String>();
        apos.put("i'm","I am");
        apos.put("can't","cannot");
        apos.put("couldn't","could not");
        String[] st = new String[]{"i'm","johny"};
        Iterator itr = apos.entrySet().iterator();
        for (int i = 0; i < st.length; i++) {
            while((itr).hasNext()) {
                if (itr.equals(st[i]))
                {
                    st[i].replace(st[i],??????(value of the matched key))
                }   
            }

            }
```

I want to compare a string with hashmap and rerplace a word with hashmap value if it matches with its key.
Above is what i am trying to do. Could anyone will please help me what i should write in place of key.

Help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You don't need to iterate over the map to find out whether an array value is a key in map. Use [`Map#containsKey()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsKey%28java.lang.Object%29) method for that. So, get rid of that iterator.

   ```
   if (map.containsKey(s[i]))
   ```
2. You don't need a replace at all. You can simply assign a new value to an array index using `=` operator.

   ```
   s[i] = newValue;
   ```
3. To get the value from the map for a particular key to set in the array, use [`Map#get(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29) method.

   ```
   map.get(s[i]);
   ```

Comment: Thanks @Rohit for replying...
I tried this :
      for (int i = 0; i < st.length; i++) {
       while(apos.containsKey(s[i])) {
              s[i]=s[i].replace(s[i],apos.get(s[i]));
                            }
           System.out.println(s[i]); 
          }


and i am getting desired result but i did't got your 2nd point, could you please elaborate it.

Thanks a ton.

Comment: @user2805482. That is not really related to your question, as I see now. I'll remove it. But just for explanation, since String are immutable, replacing anything in a String will give you a new String. It doesn't do a in-place replacement.

Comment: In your current code: change `s[i]=s[i].replace(s[i],apos.get(s[i]));` to `s[i] = apos.get(s[i]);`. That was my 3rd point. And change your `while(apos.containsKey())` to `if (apos.containsKey())`, else it will be an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:
Instead of `st[i].replace(st[i],??????(value of the matched key))`

use

```
   if(st[i].equals((String)itr.getKey()))
     st[i] = (String)itr.getValue();
```

Refer to this [tutorial](http://voices.yahoo.com/java-tips-three-ways-iterate-through-hashmap-8976889.html?cat=15) for usage details.